Does Nextjs have a function like js window onload so that the web page will not be displayed until it is fully loaded?
In js, I can easily use js window onload to make the web page display only after everything is loaded. This is very useful to me. For example, the web page will not be displayed until pictures, fonts, etc. are loaded. Make my css animation run perfectly
The problem is that Nextjs displays the web page before my image, usually the hero banner, is fully loaded. Things like the hero title with css animation start when the background is blank.
How to wait for the web page to be completed? I tried adding loading.tsx at /app folder, but it was unsuccessful. The web page started before the image was fully loaded.

which nextjs version are you using?

You're probably getting downvoted because you're working against the best interests of the web and your users. Instead of blocking the rendering of your page, use the many tools available to ensure the image loads quickly, and write your CSS to fail gracefully. Optimize your image (dimensions + compression), use loading=eager on your hero image, load it from a globally distributed CDN, and use CSS to size the container before the data loads to minimize cumulative layout shift (CLS).

It's also worth considering the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG). Animating in title text makes it inaccessible.  Displaying text over an image background without a fallback fill color that makes it legible makes it inaccessible. Blocking on fonts or images loading when users might have them disabled makes your page inaccessible. In general, if you are making your page accessible, you're making it a better experience for more people.

This solutions might help you!
You can use useState and useEffect Hook to load the content, images, and font when the webpage completely loads like this
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleLoad = () => setIsLoading(false)

    window.addEventListener('load', handleLoad)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('load', handleLoad)
  }, [])

You can use priority attribute to the Image component like this so its load before the page loads
<Image
        src="/path-to-your-image.jpg"
        alt="Hero Banner"
        layout="fill"
        objectFit="cover"
        priority
      />

